# Firebase data retrieval to web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```js
// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBz13eirmEOGD1uXOZwf6tKGnEsjfwsUFo",
    authDomain: "platformtechproject.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://platformtechproject.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "platformtechproject",
    storageBucket: "platformtechproject.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1065758005439"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  
  var database = firebase.database();
 ref msgs clllection 
 var msgRef = firebase.database().ref('survey');
```

I am trying to connect to firebase, but I continue getting these errors on chrome console failing to connect to firebase:
Chrome console error

[image]

Comment: Have you included the firebase.js file?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did not write:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

in the `<head>...</head>`

You have to write it to be able to use the firebase sdk in your project.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: Thanks it worked,now left with the second error."sizzle.js error"